# how to assign one file rows to another file rows

Tags: python, xlrd

I have two xls files each row belong to each other. I am planning to make a text file put the second row in there and name it with the first row. An example data look like this

data1.xls

```
ram
rama
rot
tab
```

data2.xls

```
myfirstattemp
mysecondattemp
mythirdattemp 
myfourthattemp
```

so It will look like this

```
ram.txt (inside is myfirstattempt)
rama.txt (inside is mysecondattemp)
.
.
.
```

I did try different things but I cannot figure it out , look what I wrote

```
import xlrd



workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook('data1.xlsx')
workbook2 = xlrd.open_workbook('data2.xlsx')
for sheet in workbook1.sheets():
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
for sheet in workbook2.sheets():
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        rowi_col0 = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
        #print filename.format(col_0, i)
        out.save(workbook1.format('sheet.nrows', i+1))
```

Comment: "each row belong to each other" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Please check your code's indentation.

Comment: @Scott Hunter means first row of the first file belongs to the first row of the second file , I gave example, it. is not clear ? if. so, I can try to make my example more clear

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what your error message is, so I've had to spec out a process. Also, your `out.save` line will crash because there is no reference to `out`.

Note that xlrd is not recommended for xlsx for security reasons, only for xls. It is recommended you use a library like openpyxl for xlsx. (In fact, if you have the latest version of xlrd it won't even let you run against xlsx - hence my code refers to xls).

```
import xlrd

# Set the references to the workbook and sheets
workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook('data1.xls')
workbook2 = xlrd.open_workbook('data2.xls')
sheet1 = workbook1.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet2 = workbook2.sheet_by_index(0)

# Pull the data into lists
names_for_files = [sheet1.cell_value(row,0) for row in range(sheet1.nrows)]
data_for_files = [sheet2.cell_value(row,0) for row in range(sheet2.nrows)]

# Iterate over the names
for out_index,output_name in enumerate(names_for_files):
    with open(f'{output_name}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data_for_files[out_index])

# Could zip the two lists together to tidy up the output
# Could pull the data as a dictionary for the same reason
```